# Find the matrix and determine if the transformation is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the matrix of the transformation with respect to the basis $v_1=\cos t$ and $v_2=\sin t$, and determine if $T$ is an isomorphism.

$T(f(t))=f(t-\pi/4)$

I understand that I have to evaluate $\cos(t-\pi/4)$ and $\sin(t-\pi/4)$, but I don't know how to evaluate them so that they are linear combinations of $v_1$ and $v_2$. For example, $\cos(t-\pi/4) = av_1+bv_2$ for scalars $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Use formulas $$\cos (t-\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cos{t}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sin{t}$$ and
$$\sin (t-\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sin{t}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}cos{t}$$